# iOS: can receipts be reused to check for purchases?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, receipt-validation

is it possible to send an iOS receipt to the server and the server checks periodically with that same receipt if (new) purchases are made? Or are only in app purchases returned up to the point the receipt has been sent to the server?

For my use case I need to check "future" purchases with the same receipt as well, but while testing with sandbox it seems as if only purchases until the time of the receipt are returned from the App Store.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateRemotely.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573-CH104-SW4) this varies based on the type of you in-app purchases. If your receipt containing auto-renewable subscriptions the response you will receive from apple will contain two additional fields "latest_receipt" and "latest_receipt_info", you can use these fields to determine whether the subscriptions are currently active or not. If your receipt doesn't containing auto-renewable subscriptions than you will only receive the "receipt" field which will be a JSON representation of **the receipt that was sent for verification**.